# How can I use ASP.NET's Label IDs in a FOR loop in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry if the title is not clear enough.
I have about 20 Label and 20 TextBoxes in my asp.Net form and the Visible attribute for all of them is false.

I'm willing to change some of their Visible attributes to true, depending on a given number. How can I use those Labels and TextBoxes' IDs in a FOR loop?

I've named the Labels like this: Label1, Label2, Label3, etc.

p.s: The ParameterCount's value varies from 1 to 20.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= parameterCount; i++)
{
    Label[i].Visible = True; //I know it's wrong, but something like this
}
```

Example 1:  ParameterCount = 4

(Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4).Visible = True

Example2: Parameter Count=2

(Label1, Label2).Visible = True

Comment: How do you give IDs to your labels?

Comment: Label1, Label2, Label3, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put your label in an array:

```
Label[] arr = new Label[] { label1, label5, label10, lable13, label14 };
for (int i = 0; i < ParameterCount; ++i)
   arr[i].Visible = true;
```

Provided that `ParameterCount <= arr.Length`

Comment: It won't work neither, because each time the ParameterCount's value is different.

Comment: No, it works definitely. Just put your labels in the array in THE CORRECT order. After that you loop over only `ParameterCount` elements from the beginning of array.

Comment: If the order cannot be fit in a single array, consider adding more arrays as you want. You then decide what array to use depending on the value of `ParameterCount`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Page.FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Label l = this.FindControl($"Label{i}") as Label;

if (l != null)
{
    // use the label `l` here
}
```

If the label isn't a top element, you have to find it inside the container control.

See a full example on MSDN: [How to: Access Server Controls by ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could place those labels or textboxes inside an `asp:Panel`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server">
    ... your textboxes and labels come here
</asp:Panel>
```

and then simply toggle the visibility of this panel:

```
myPanel.Visible = true; // or false if you wish
```

Comment: I don't think it works, because in one case it may be 2 labels or in another 10 labels. Your example sets all of them visible.

Comment: I think you over-simplified your sample then @iminiki. Darin answers you based on your code in the question.